# What is the Japanese term for a gamer?

Tags: colloquial-language

As in "some one who plays video games". Could I just use ゲーマー?

Comment: And for game freaks/geeks/addicts ゲームオタク

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As rintaun says, ゲーマー is the most general term for "some one who plays video games".

In its narrower sense, when describing a person, it can mean a "hardcore gamer" as opposed to just ゲーム好き (げーむずき, casual gamer). For example, if someone wants to say she's just a casual gamer, she might say things like `ゲーム好きだけど、ゲーマーじゃありません。`

If you need to differentiate between different gamer types, there are terms that roughly corresponds to the english ones.

- ライトゲーマー: casual gamer
- ミドルゲーマー: mid-core gamer
- ヘビーゲーマー: hardcore gamer
- コアゲーマー: especially avid fans among mid-core gamers

(From Wikipedia articles: [ゲーマー](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC) and [Gamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamer))

Comment: I just wanted to further add that I bought the Gerard Butler film 'Gamer' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamer_%28film%29) on DVD and it also used the spelling ゲーマー on the box.

Answer (score 8):

That's correct. ゲーマー is the word that is generally used.

Comment: And for plural, add たち?

Comment: For multiple gamers, just ゲーマー will work. たち actually makes it refer to the/a **group** of gamers specifically.

Comment: For plural, you can try adding ズ (ゲーマーズ), but it'd turn into a merchandise shop instead!